# Index was outside the bounds of array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

When I try run the aplication, it shows the `Index was outside the bounds of the array` at line `float[] u_f = a[userid];`
Any idea?
PS. the user ID can be every integer,but I take the index of the integer with is between(0, 1143600 for item) and (0, 89395 for user) and my calculation is based on that.Then, my calculation is based on the index of `userid` value which is stored in array a not based on the value of `userid`.
   Thanks in advance

```
        float[][] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 89395).Select(i => new float[100]).ToArray();
        float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray();
        int[] c = new int[1258038];
        int[] d = new int [92160];
        ........
        public float dotproduct(int userid, int itemid)
        {
            result = 0f;
            float[] u_f = a[userid];   //  <----Error Line (index was outside the bounds of array)
            float[] i_f = b[itemid];

            for (int i = 0; i < u_f.Length; i++)
            {
                result += u_f[i] * i_f[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        private void btn_recomm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_itemid.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text))
            {
                    int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                    int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
                    int userseq=Array.IndexOf(d, sc);
                    var results = new List<float>(1143600);
                    for (int z = 0; z <= 1143600; z++)
                    {
                        results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
                    }
                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
                    {
                        sb1.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", d[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
                        sb1.AppendLine();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());


            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_itemid.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text))
            {
                int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text);
                int userseq0 = Array.IndexOf(d, uid);
                int itemseq0 = Array.IndexOf(c, iid);
                dotproduct(userseq0, itemseq0);
                MessageBox.Show("The Score of item id " + itemseq0 + " is " + result);
            }
```

Comment: Error says it all, step through your code - `a[userid]` is outside the array, so in example, if you had  `0 - 4` indexies and `userid` was anything higher than 4, it would throw exception.

Comment: What is the value of `userid`?

Comment: The error occurs because the `userid` value is equal or greater than the array length.

Comment: Your array has two dimension float[][] a but in error line you try to find with only one dimension float[] u_f = a[userid];

Comment: I edited my code and add some explanation to it, may you chack it again,please? @SonerGönül

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `dotproduct` gets called with `userid` value being equal to or greater than `a.Length`.

If that's not supposed to happen then add this line before declaring `u_f` array:

```
Debug.Assert(a.Length > userid);
```

Of course this won't solve the problem in itself but it will ensure you that whenever such a situation happens while you are testing, it won't go unnoticed or swallowed.

As a side note, clearer variable names would make it easier on you to read your code and figure out issues. Using actual types instead of jagged arrays would likely help too, if possible.

Comment: the user ID can be every integer,but I take the index of the integer with is between(0, 1143600 for item) and (0, 89395 for user) and my calculation is based on that.Then, my calculation is based on the index of userid value which is stored in array a not based on the value of userid @crono

Answer (score 0):

It means the value of `userID` is higher than the maximum index number of the array `a`. The maximum index is count - 1.

The error message mentions that.

Also, it looks like `a` is two dimensional. Could this be your problem?

Comment: the user ID can be every integer,but I take the index of the integer with is between(0, 1143600 for item) and (0, 89395 for user) and my calculation is based on that.Then, my calculation is based on the index of userid value which is stored in array a not based on the value of userid.

Answer (score 0):

replace a[userid] with

```
 a[userid-1]
```

Comment: We don't even know the value of userid.